# CS50P PSET2: Setting up my twttr: How to union two string

Tags: python, list, cs50

```py
vowel = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]

vowel_remove = input("Input: ")
print("Output: ", end="")

for vowels in vowel:
    lower_vowel = vowels.lower()
    # print(lower_vowel)
    if vowels in vowel_remove:
        print(vowel_remove.replace(vowels, ""))

print()
```

```
Input: Apple
```

```py
Output: Appl
pple
```

I get two output with each one of the vowel is removed one by one and making two output.

Is there a way to union the different string like seeing the similarity of the characters and removing the odd one like for example

`Appl` and `pple` the similar ones are `ppl` and the odd one from each of them are `A` and `e`

is it possible to union `ppl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code iterates the input and removes the vowels and save the non vowels to an output variable.

```
vowel = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
vowel_remove = input("Input: ")
print("Output: ", end="")

output = ""
for char in vowel_remove:
    if char in vowel:
        continue
    else:
        output += char
print(output)
```

> output

```
Input: Apple
Output: ppl
```

To find unique characters in 2 strings you can use

```
print(''.join(set('Appl').intersection('pple')))
```

But this will remove repeating characters for example, 'p' in the above case.

> output

```
lp
```

Answer (score 0):

This `print(vowel_remove.replace(vowels, ""))` executes each time a vowel is encountered. It does not change the contents of `vowel_remove`. IMO looking for a way to UNION the "result" is more work than needs to be done. If you remove the `print` from the above statement, `vowel_remove` will be changed, and you can print the final result after the loop is complete.